# How to change method name for has_through rails association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create two has many relations to the same destination tables but I am unable to override the default method name rails creates when defining the association.

The following is the case:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :conference_attendees, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :conference_organizers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :conferences, through: :conference_attendees, class_name: 'attending', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :conferences, through: :conference_organizers, source: :conference, dependent: :destroy

class ConferenceOrganizer < ApplicationRecord
  alias_attribute :organizers, :users
  belongs_to :conference
  belongs_to :user
end

class ConferenceAttendee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :conference
  belongs_to :user
end

class Conference < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :conference_attendees, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :conference_organizers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :conference_attendees, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :organizers, through: :conference_organizers, source: :user, dependent: :destroy
```

I am trying to access all the conferences that a user attended and then all conferences that a user organized using something like following:

```
User.find(id: <id>).organizing
User.find(id: <id>).attending
```

but I am unable to and

```
User.find(id: <id>).conferences
```

defaults to organizing conferences. How do I access attending conferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are doing a join on the same two tables it might be cleaner to do one join table and add a field called status to distinguish organizer from attendee. That way you can add other status values such as "presenter".

set up the table `rails g model Registration user:references conference:references status:string`; `rake db:migrate`

Set up the model associations:

```
# app/models/user.rb
has_many :registrations, dependent: :destroy

# app/models/conference.rb
has_many :registrations, dependent: :destroy

# app/models/registration.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :conference
scope :attendees, -> { where( status: "Attendee") }
scope :organizers, -> { where( status: "Organizer") }
```

Then to show the attendees and organizers on the conference show page:

```
# app/controllers/conferences_controller.rb
def show
  @conference = Conference.find(params[:id])
  @attendee_registrations = @conference.registrations.attendees
  @organizer_registrations = @conference.registrations.organizers
end

# app/views/conferences/show.html.erb
<h3>Organizers</h3>
<% @organizer_registrations.each do |registration| %>
  <li><%= link_to(registration.user.name, registration.user) %></li>
<% end %>
<h3>Attendees</h3>
<% @attendee_registrations.each do |registration| %>
  <li><%= link_to(registration.user.name, registration.user) %></li>
<% end %>
```

Then to show the conferences on the user's show page:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @attending_registrations = @user.registrations.attendees
  @organizing_registrations = @user.registrations.organizers   
end

# app/views/users/show.html.erb
<h3>Conferences Organizing</h3>
<% @organizing_registrations.each do |registration| %>
  <li><%= link_to(registration.conference.name, registration.conference) %><br> 
  Date: <%= registration.conference.date %></li>
<% end %>
<h3>Conferences Attending</h3>
<% @attending_registrations.each do |registration| %>
  <li><%= link_to(registration.conference.name, registration.conference) %><br> 
  Date: <%= registration.conference.date %></li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want two join tables on Users and Conferences you can set it up this way.

```
# app/models/user.rb
has_many :conference_attendees, dependent: :destroy
has_many :conference_organizers, dependent: :destroy
has_many :attending, through: :conference_attendees, source: :conference
has_many :organizing, through: :conference_organizers, source: :conference

# app/models/conference.rb
has_many :conference_attendees, dependent: :destroy
has_many :conference_organizers, dependent: :destroy
has_many :attendees, through: :conference_attendees, source: :user
has_many :organizers, through: :conference_organizers, source: :user

# app/models/conference_attendee.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :conference

# app/models/conference_organizer.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :conference
```

Then to show the attendees and organizers on the conference show page:

```
# app/controllers/conferences_controller.rb
def show
  @conference = Conference.find(params[:id])
  @attendees = @conference.attendees
  @organizers = @conference.organizers
end

# app/views/conferences/show.html.erb
<h3>Organizers</h3>
<% @organizers.each do |user| %>
  <li><%= user.name %></li>
<% end %>
<h3>Attendees</h3>
<% @attendees.each do |user| %>
  <li><%= user.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

Then to show the conferences on the user's show page:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @attending = @user.attending
  @organizing = @user.organizing    
end

# app/views/users/show.html.erb
<h3>Conferences Organizing</h3>
<% @organizing.each do |conference| %>
  <li><%= link_to(conference.name, conference) %><br> Date: <%= conference.date %></li>
<% end %>
<h3>Conferences Attending</h3>
<% @attending.each do |conference| %>
  <li><%= link_to(conference.name, conference) %><br> Date: <%= conference.date %></li>
<% end %>
```

That being said it may be cleaner to use one join table rather than two. I'll put that in a separate answer.